# import new component into LT Spice with .cir file

Tags: ltspice

my desperate attempt to simulate a circuit led me here.

I have a low noise amplifier which has a HEMT as its transistor.  (ATF38143).  I have been trying to create a component in LT Spice and came across [this website](http://www.hp.woodshot.com/hprfhelp/design/SPICE/fets.htm).
The page linked here is a .cir file for ATF34143 and it was the closest HEMT I could find.

I copied and pasted the script in a text editor and saved it in the .cir format.  Then, I opened it with LT Spice, highlighted the name of the HEMT in the first line of the .cir file to create a new component.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to simulate the circuit, it results in an error.  I have tried the same simulation without the user defined HEMT and the result of the simulation appeared reasonable.

I have also tried the .cir file of a different transistor from the same website ([linked here](http://www.hp.woodshot.com/hprfhelp/design/SPICE/bjts.htm#AT310)) and went through the exact same steps to create a component corresponding to the .cir file.  It worked smoothly.

Could someone take a look at the content of the cir file for the ATF34143 transistor shown on the website and point out what's wrong with it? Given that I was able to create a new component with a different .cir file, I am certain what's in the .cir file for ATF34143 is wrong.

Shown below is what the website says the .cir file should have. (It's a bit unclear which parts should be in the .cir file given that there are two instances of ".SUBCKT" and ".ENDS")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the model into something LTspice understands.  The model had a few issues with the SPICE syntax (LTspice is pretty strict about using Spice3 derived syntax).

Here is a updated model, and a discussion of the changes and compromises will follow:

```
*ATF-34143 packaged FET model
*LTspice adaption
.SUBCKT ATF34143  16   14   15
RR2 2   1   0.1  
RR9 4   3   0.1  
RR5 1   5   0.1  
LL2 5   SOURCE  0.1nH  
LL7 SOURCE  7   0.1nH  
LL6 SOURCE  8   0.1nH  
RR6 8   2   0.1  
RR7 7   2   0.1  
RR8 DRAIN   9   0.1  
LL5 9   11  0.1nH  
LL8 2   15  0.05nH  
LL10    15  1   0.1nH  
LL1 14  4   0.8nH  
LL9 11  16  0.6nH  
CC3 11  2   0.15e-12  
CC4 1   4   0.15e-12  
LL4 3   GATE    0.1nH  
*CALL DIE MODEL
XDIE DRAIN GATE SOURCE  ATF34
.ENDS
****     GaAs MESFET MODEL PARAMETERS
.SUBCKT ATF34   D   G   S
CC1 D S 0.04pF
RR1 G GATE 1
Z34 D GATE S BATF34143
.ENDS
.MODEL BATF34143 nmf ( LEVEL=2, Vto=-0.95, Beta=0.24, 
+                     Lambda=0.09, Alpha=4, B=0.8, Pb=0.7, 
+                     Cgs=0.8pF, Cgd=0.16pF, Rd=0.25, 
+                     Rs=0.125, Is=1nA)
```

I had to remove the spaces between the values and units in the model, which accounted for a lot of the ignored parameters right off the bat.

And LTSpice does have a `GASFET` model, but it is named `nmf` (for n channel MESFET).  Changing the model to the correct type for LTSpice further reduces the ignored parameters.

Most of the those parameters are secondary parameters (and thus are included in a model for convenience, but can be modeled just as well using a netlist around the model) which I accounted for in the ATF34 subcircuit.  Specifically, ohmic gate resistance and fixed drain to source capacitance.

The Tnom parameter is simply the nominal temperature, which is a global parameter in LTSpice and already defaults to 27 anyway, so that isn't needed.

`Delta` is the power law for triode region operation and isn't accounted for by LTSpice's nmf MESFET model, so we will have to do without.  But if your application is a LNA, then I would assume you'd only care about the saturation region, in which case this doesn't really matter for your application anyway and shouldn't influence your simulation meaningfully.

`Vbi` is just a different term for the gate bias voltage, which is referred to by `Pb` in LTSpice, so I changed it to the correct parameter name.  That leaves just one unrecognized parameter, `P`.

This is the drain noise coefficient, and is not part of the model.  The Statz model includes the flicker noise coefficient, and LTSpice's model DOES support that parameter, so I added it (`Kf`).

It should work reasonably well but the noise might not be modeling drain noise noise correctly, and of course triode region voltage to current power law behavior.

Comment: Now I see I omitted the MESFET. My point was that you could use it as something else, but then the results should not be the ones expected. +1, and shame on me.